# Pivot Data into New Column Names - Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

working in Oracle SQL and I have the following data set:

[image]

My goal is to get it into a dataset that looks like this, I'm assuming I will have to use some form of a pivot function, but I'm not sure how I would go about creating new column names that don't already exist in the same step:

[image]

I am only providing one example of my total dataset, there will be plenty of INDIV_ID records with a varying number of possible purchase dates (i.e., not every INDIV_ID will have 10 purchase dates. Some could have more, some could have less)

Thank you in advance,
Nick

Comment: The structure you started with is suitable for varying numbers of dates. The structure you're aiming for is not. It's a SQL anti-pattern, this is not the right thing to do in SQL. SQL is not Excel, stick to the normalised (original) data structure, that's the one Designed for use with SQL.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this if you know the number of columns you want:

```
select indiv_id,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then prch_dt end) as dt_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then prch_dt end) as dt_2,
       . . .
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by indiv_id order by prch_dt) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by indiv_id;
```

If you don't know the number of columns, then you need to use dynamic SQL -- which is quite cumbersome.

Alternatively, you could aggregate the values into a single delimited string:

```
select indiv_id,
       list_agg(prch_dt, ',') within group (order by prch_dt)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by indiv_id order by prch_dt) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by indiv_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Conditional Aggregation in such a way that to create a select statement string to pivot those columns while enumerating through use of `ROW_NUMBER()` function for each individual date in order to assign different integer value dynamically even if there exists equal date values within a stored function which returns a value in `SYS_REFCURSOR` type such as

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Fn_Pivot_Table RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR IS
  v_recordset SYS_REFCURSOR;
  v_sql       VARCHAR2(32767);
  v_cols      VARCHAR2(32767);   
BEGIN
  SELECT LISTAGG( 'MAX(CASE WHEN rn = '||rn||' THEN prch_dt END ) AS  "Date_'||rn||'"'  , ',')
                   WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY rn )
                 
    INTO v_cols
    FROM ( SELECT prch_dt,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY indiv_id ORDER BY prch_dt) AS rn FROM t );
      
  v_sql :='SELECT indiv_id,'|| v_cols ||
          '  FROM ( SELECT t.*,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY indiv_id ORDER BY prch_dt) AS rn FROM t )
            GROUP BY indiv_id';

  OPEN v_recordset FOR v_sql;
  RETURN v_recordset;
END;
/
```

where `t` represents your table purchase date values of which needs to be pivoted.

Then call that function from the SQL Developer's console as

```
SQL> DECLARE
    result SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
   :result := Fn_Pivot_Table;
END;
/

SQL> PRINT result;
```

Comment: Interesting, it seems like the first part of this works. But when I try to call the function from the SQL Dev's console, I get unknown command errors

Comment: Hi @Ciccotelli412 , what error do you get ?